# Dynamic vector creation

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to create a vector dynamically in dependence of `n` (for example 1 or 4). If my `n` is bigger I need to have more values in my vector.

```
for i=1:(N-n)
    yvecT(i)=y(n+i); % Achtung, Zeilenvektor
    for k=n:-1:1
        F(i-1+n,:)=[-y(i) -y(i-k) u(i) u(i-k)];
    end  
end

%n=1  F(i,:)=[-y(i)  u(i)];
%n=2  F(i,:)=[-y(i) -y(i-1) u(i) u(i-1)];    
%n=4  F(i,:)=[-y(i) -y(i-1) -y(i-2) -y(i-3) u(i) u(i-1) u(i-2) u(i-3)];
```

it is a function used to identify a System....

Comment: your question is quite hard to understand, why when n =4, you have F(i-3,:) instead of your function F(i-1+n,:) - which should be F(i+3,:)?

Comment: Hope this edit clarifys it. I could easily just create the F array based on the n but I would like to dynamically create it

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you mean each row of your F matrix should have different number of elements, based on the value of 'n'? It would be useful to have a standalone, run-able example that someone can run.

Comment: Here is how it could look like in the complete function. Well there is a Blackbox PT2 function http://pastebin.com/JQ12V9iB What i really want, is to replace the if(n==2) in my function so i can use it for different n whatsoever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have posted the for-loop (with the if-statements) from the link in the question and stated that you wanted it to work for an arbitary `n`. That would have made everyone understand your problem. I think the easiest way to do what you do is to use subreferencing. So in case `n==2` we do not have

```
F(i-1,:)=[-y(i) -y(i-1) u(i) u(i-1)];
```

but rather,

```
F(i-(n-1),:)=[-y(i:-1:(n-1)) u(i:-1:(n-1))];
```

This looks messier, but it works for any arbitary `n`. Some other comments about the code. The variable `i` is also a function returning the imaginary unit. By naming a variable `i` you overload this function. The recommended way is to use `1i` as an imaginary unit, so it is not critical, but in case you do not necessarily need `i` as a variable you should consider another name. Also it is easier for us to understand in case you write in english. So in general, prefer comments in english when posting here.